# mysql_fetch_array into array to check if checkbox should be checked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called products_to_colors that has 2 columns, product_id and color_id.

I am trying to get the results from said table into an array so that I can check if the values are already there so a checkbox can be shown as checked.

here is the query code portion:

```
$color_id_query = tep_db_query("select color_id from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_COLORS . " where products_id = '" . (int)$product['products_id'] . "'");

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($color_id_query)) {
           $key=$row['color_id'];
            $qa[$key] = array(); 

       }
```

And here is the checkbox portion:

```
<tr>
        <td class="main">Colors</td>
        <td class="main">
         <?php echo '&nbsp;Green' . tep_draw_checkbox_field('color_id[]', '1', in_array('1', $qa)) . '&nbsp;Turquoise' . tep_draw_checkbox_field('color_id[]', '2', in_array('2', $qa)); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

The function tep_draw_checkbox_field is defines as:

```
 function tep_draw_checkbox_field($name, $value = '', $checked = false, $compare = '') {
    return tep_draw_selection_field($name, 'checkbox', $value, $checked, $compare);
  }
```

So basically I am just trying to use the in_array function for the checked field but I don't think i am using mysql_fetch_array properly to insert the values into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($color_id_query)) {
            $qa[] = $row['color_id'];
       }
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I will accept this answer as soon as I can!